Can't get sc.read_10x_mtx to read my data
I have a (hopefully) quick question for you this morning. Whenever I use the sc.read_10x_mtx (and below is my text block) I get the following error.
adata = sc.read_10x_mtx(
    'filtered_feature_bc_matrix_folder/',
    var_names='gene_symbols',
    cache=True)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 adata = sc.read_10x_mtx(
      2     'filtered_feature_bc_matrix_folder/',
      3     var_names='gene_symbols',
      4     cache=True)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scanpy/readwrite.py:491, in read_10x_mtx(path, var_names, make_unique, cache, cache_compression, gex_only, prefix)
    489 prefix = "" if prefix is None else prefix
    490 is_legacy = (path / f"{prefix}genes.tsv").is_file()
--> 491 adata = _read_10x_mtx(
    492     path,
    493     var_names=var_names,
    494     make_unique=make_unique,
    495     cache=cache,
    496     cache_compression=cache_compression,
    497     prefix=prefix,
    498     is_legacy=is_legacy,
    499 )
    500 if is_legacy or not gex_only:
    501     return adata

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scanpy/readwrite.py:533, in _read_10x_mtx(path, var_names, make_unique, cache, cache_compression, prefix, is_legacy)
    531 var_names_idx = pd.Index(genes[1].values)
    532 if make_unique:
--> 533     var_names_idx = anndata.utils.make_index_unique(var_names_idx)
    534 adata.var_names = var_names_idx
    535 adata.var["gene_ids"] = genes[0].values

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anndata/utils.py:250, in make_index_unique(index, join)
    248 while True:
    249     counter[v] += 1
--> 250     tentative_new_name = v + join + str(counter[v])
    251     if tentative_new_name not in values_set:
    252         values_set.add(tentative_new_name)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Just hopeful for any advice! Thank you very much. 

Using sc.read_10x_mtx and having my data properly import from 10x matrix software

You cannot add a string to a number (23 + "5"). You first need to convert any numeric value in the string to its correct integer or float type.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
